# How To write one column array to csv file

Tags: php, string, post, fputcsv

I am trying to write post variables to a csv file but it writes everything in one line separated by comma

```
<?php

$list= array($_POST['purchases']);
$file = fopen("purchases.csv", "w");

foreach ($list as $line)
{
fputcsv($file, $line); 
}

fclose($file); 
?>
```

Result in purchases.csv file

```
Marilyn,Nancy,Johan,Carol,Juanic,Shirley
```

But I want every string value on seperated line

```
Marilyn
Nancy
Johan
Carol
Juanic
Shirley
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all of your values are in a CSV value from the front end, you can just write this out as a CSV but with line breaks instead of commas...

```
$file = fopen("purchases.csv", "w");
fputcsv($file, $_POST['purchases'], PHP_EOL); 
fclose($file);
```